# Element Not visible error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In site [goIndigo](https://book.goindigo.in/?wt_mc=googlesearch.brand&gclid=Cj0KEQjw6Ya5BRDdyOewyo_Z_64BEiQA-fVKexBncPbn5uMUxePyvGLVo_r4wUw9Y_GeMNNOqMY8hY4aAqdb8P8HAQ#viewchange)  and navigating to View/Change booking   and selecting E mail itenary ,  a pop comes , I want to close that Pop up using Close button in Pop up:

But I am getting Error that Element is not visible;

My code is as below:

```
WebDriver drv= new FirefoxDriver();
drv.get("https://book.goindigo.in/?wt_mc=googlesearch.brand&gclid=CjwKEAjwxoG5BRCC7ezlzNmR8HUSJAAre36jSbKPBIdunIi2WUecy4wVPCFnqTv73JMeG95oUjTquxoCRlPw_wcB");
drv.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Flight Status']")).click();
drv.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='View / Change Booking']")).click();
drv.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='indiGoRetrieveBooking_RecordLocator']")).click();
drv.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='indiGoRetrieveBooking_RecordLocator']")).sendKeys("abcdef");
drv.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='indiGoRetrieveBooking_EmailAddress']")).sendKeys("pandey");
drv.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='emailButtonId']")).click();
String mainhandle = drv.getWindowHandle();
WebElement from =drv.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonGlbl']"));
from.click();
```

Comment: ur work flow is not clear, after going to ur site, than i enter booking reference and email/last name, than i click on email itenary and the pop up opens. u want to close that pop up?

Answer (score 0):

First try to put `Thread.sleep()` before you look for element, just to wait for element arise. It is quick solution just to check if the problem is too fast execution:

`drv.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='emailButtonId']")).click();
String mainhandle = drv.getWindowHandle();
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement from =drv.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonGlbl']"));`

Then if everything is ok, you can change from `sleep()` to more nice solution:

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(drv, 10);        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonGlbl']")));`

Comment: You can also set implicityWait to avoid situation like that at any place of your site:  `drv.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Answer (score 0):

i assume that, ur close pop up comes up.

if u want to close that pop up, just use

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("$('#emailItinerarySuccessModal .indigo-submit').click();");
```

Comment: Can you also explain how did  come to know the X path? (''$('#emailItenarySuccessModal.indigo-submit').click:");    usually we use javascript executor for scrolling window ryt?

Comment: By javascript u can do click , change attrbute value also...and if this works pls accpt the answer...thanks....:)

Comment: Thanks again   :) , Can you give me any link where I can study how  to find  X path using javascript .